# Google Scripts run on any App open

Tags: google-apps-script

In a google script, is there a way to make a trigger so that a standalone script runs when any type of Google App (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides, etc.) is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer = No, this raises a number of security concerns.

Longer answer = Standalone scripts can create triggers using the ['trigger builder'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forSpreadsheet(String)) function. I suppose in theory you can use this to loop through all of the files the user owns, and create an 'onOpen' trigger for every file in the users drive. I can see this getting unusably messy very quickly if they have more then a handful of files though.